# Initial storyboard view controller not loading swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, ios8-share-extension

My application was loads fine and once i have added share extension to app, its not loading initial view controller, Just showing blank screen? Any solutions?

Do we need to use same bundle id for both app and app extension? I beleive, same app group is fine?

Please confirm

Thanks!

Comment: Can you write warning log which is display in xcode log?

Comment: Yes,

 [Application] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

but i have set initial view controller, now the above log disapper and still issue there, just blank screen.

Comment: Have you write any code in appdelegare in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: Yes,   self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashBoardScreen") as! DashBoardScreen
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: You haven't need to write code in appDelegate if you set entry point in storyboard. remove appDelegare code and run it.

Comment: Yes you are right. i didn't set in storyboard, just handled in code. but it throws entry point error, so i remove app delegate code and set in storyboard .. still its not works. One thing, it works before adding extension. confusing..


And one more,

While i run extension target, it throws 

"Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle"

Actually extension should call "MainInterface.storboard" but why it refers main storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the appDelegate to instantiate the initial ViewController

1. Locate your Info.plist file. right click > Open as > Source code
2. Inside your Info.plist file remove :

`<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key> 
 <string>Main</string>`